# I can't do an installment calculation with an installment fee addition in Shopify Liquid

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

```
<p style="font-size: 18px">
  ou 12x de
  <span style="color: #00dd70">{{ product.price | plus: product.price divided_by: 17,28% | divided_by: 12 | money}}</span>
  sem juros
</p>
```

Shopify always returns error when I use %

how can i calculate the value of the product divided by 12 times the rate of 17.28% on shopify liquid language? I couldn't find it in the documentation.

This would be the value of the installments that the customer would have to pay when choosing the installment of up to 12 installments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do percentage calculation within liquid. You need to calculate the formula to get your number.

If I understand it correctly you want to calculate 12 rates of a an amount increase by 17.2%.
So let's say your initial price is `X`, the price with interest is `117.2/100*X` and if you divide that by 12 you have `117.2/100/12*x`. `117.2/12` is `0.097`.

So your piece of code becomes

```
<p style="font-size: 18px">
  ou 12x de
  <span style="color: #00dd70">{{ product.price | times: 0.097 | money}}</span>
  sem juros
</p>
```

To make  the code clearer and avoid magic numbers

```
<p style="font-size: 18px">
  ou 12x de
  {% assign interest = 1.172 %}
  {% assign rates = 12 %}
  {% assign factor = interest | divided_by: rates %}
  <span style="color: #00dd70">{{ product.price | times: factor | money}}</span>
  sem juros
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, it helped me to understand better. 